# How to easily manipulate a pose

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I have a relatively large bone structure that I now want to set the pose for. Is there an easier way to modify the pose than to rotate each bone? Is the maybe a way to activate proportional editing mode or move the points of the bone rather than rotating? Are there some controls that make pose editing faster and easier?

Comment: This is done through proper rigging. A good rig will have controler bones which nake setting up poses easy. It is uncommen to manipulate the deforming bones. Upload a blend or images of your armature for more help.

Comment: Rather than uploading my specific blend file, could I get a general answer of what to do in the future? How should I set up my bones next time?

Comment: There are various technique based on what shape your object is (eg a matress, a tube, a cable). Most of the time you rig with IK constraint. I can add a general answer later.